# whenever loading url and reloading getting white blank page and it loading 2 -3 secs it's coming

Tags: magento2.2

We are working `magento2.2` version hosted website.

Everything working Fine but when loading website `www.example.com` it's getting some time white Blank page and again loading page as usual after 2-3sec.

varnish we are using to cache pages 
through `aws cloudfront` we are distributing the files.

**note: time to first byte(TTFB) option is critical with server.**

can any one advise me what causing this to getting blank pages all urls not single but only less time not continuous.